# Need proper output in the format below

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in this format:

| courseID | studentID | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | s1 | pass |
| c1 | s2 | fail |
| c2 | s1 | fail |
| c3 | s3 | pass |

I want results in this format:

| courseID | studentID | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| course | total students | passed students |

I have tried this query

```
SELECT course, count(course) AS "total_students"
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE status = 'pass') AS passed
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE status = 'fail') AS failed
FROM table
GROUP BY course;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your subqueries are lacking `WHERE` criteria so they are just counting *all* the rows in the table. What you want is aggregation. Specifically conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT Course,
       COUNT(*) AS TotalStudents,
       COUNT(CASE result WHEN 'pass' THEN 1 END) AS Passed,
       COUNT(CASE result WHEN 'fail' THEN 1 END) AS Failed
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Course;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
select t1.c as course
    , t1.t as “total _students”
    , t2.tp as “passed_students”
    , t3.tf as “failed_students”
from
(select course as c, count(course) as t from table group by course) as t1,
(select course as c, count(course) as tp from table where status = ‘pass’ group by course) as t2,
(select course as c, count(course) as tf from table where status = ‘fail’ group by course) as t3 where t1.c=t2.c and t2.c=t3.c
```

Comment: A good answer explains how it works as well as providing working code.

Comment: Side note, Smart Quotes (`“`,`”`,`‘`,`’`) don't work in SQL; they have to be "normal" ones (`"` and `'`). One reason why you shouldn't write your queries in a word processing. :)

Comment: Also, although this will work, 3 scans of the table could me somewhat unperformant.

Comment: Please don't teach people this old, comma separated join style. `JOIN` is easier to read, write and maintain

Comment: The other solution will almost certainly perform better and is a lot neater.

Comment: @Larnu And another reason why you should put column names in brackets `[]` rather than quotes `""`

Comment: I'm not specifically opposed to use double quotes, @Charlieface , they are the ANSI delimit identifier after all, which *can* make SQL more transferable between RDBMS.